Custom config loading from yaml file into @Configuration marked classes in spring boot
I am working on a project and we have run into the need of injected some fields into a @Configuration marked class, without explicitly mentioning the field names (The way we usually do while writing spring configuration classes).
For example, right now, if I have a class 'Parent' and I inside it I want to have fields 'child1' and 'child2', I will have to write the config class something like this :
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="parent")
public class Parent {
    public String child1;
    public String child2;
}


Given that my yaml looks like this :
parent : 
   child1 : value1
   child2 : value2

Spring will bind the values of child1 and child2 to the class.
How I want to structure my Parent class is something like this, given that my yaml still looks the same :
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="parent")
public class Parent {
    public List<T> children; //T signifies some interface/class that I will give to children
}


I am aware this will involve some deep dive into how spring loads configurations from external files, but I am not sure which direction to look into. Any help is greatly appreciated.
I have looked into ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor, ConfigurationPropertiesBinder, Binder and a few other classes, but cant figure out where exactly the class and field mapping from yaml is being done. A more streamlined direction is what I want.

That is not possible. How should the yaml loading deduce T and what to create and bind to? Without doing all that manually this won't work and when doing it manually it kind of defeats the purpose of the configuration in the first place.
